# Build failure for GNU classpath

Tags: java, linux, gnu-classpath

i'm trying to install classpath 0.98, steps:

```
./configure --enable-jni --disable-gtk-peer --disable-gconf-peer --disable-plugin
```

and no show error, but when i tip make:

```
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/sda1/tce/optional/classpath-0.98/lib' 
true
top_builddir=.. top_srcdir=.. /bin/sh ./gen-classlist.sh standard
Adding java source files from srcdir '..'.
Adding java source files from VM directory ../vm/reference
javac -Xlint:unchecked,cast,divzero,empty,finally,overrides  -J-Xmx768M -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -   bootclasspath '' -classpath ../vm/reference:..:../external/w3c_dom:../external/sax:../external/    relaxngDatatype:../external/jsr166:.:: -d . @classes
make[1]: *** [compile-classes] Killed
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/sda1/tce/optional/classpath-0.98/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a bit strange!

> How can i fix it?

What you need to do is find out what caused it.  The cause will determine the fix.

My guess would be that your build has died because it filled up the disc.

---

Out of curiosity, why are you building Classpath?  It is normally only interesting to people who are trying to build their own JVMs.  If you simply want a JVM that you want to try some private experiments with, you would be better off checking out OpenJDK.

And if you are trying to build an existing JVM that uses Classpath, you need to read and follow that JVM's build instructions carefully.  They often use a version/copy of Classpath that includes JVM specific code and / or that isn't at the HEAD for some reason.

Comment: I need classpath because i want to use jamVM

Excuse me for me English.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Thanks, i have find a classpath package and I have installed it and jamvm work fine.